# Mute renderer output when calling through script

Tags: python, scripting

When calling `bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)` from in a script
I pass to blender with `blender --background --python myscript.py`, I get a very verbose output:

```
Fra:1 Mem:13.02M (0.00M, Peak 13.03M) | Time:00:00.00 | Preparing Scene data
Fra:1 Mem:13.02M (0.00M, Peak 13.03M) | Time:00:00.00 | Creating Shadowbuffers
Fra:1 Mem:13.02M (0.00M, Peak 13.03M) | Time:00:00.00 | Raytree.. preparing
Fra:1 Mem:13.05M (0.00M, Peak 13.05M) | Time:00:00.00 | Raytree.. building
Fra:1 Mem:13.05M (0.00M, Peak 13.11M) | Time:00:00.00 | Raytree finished
Fra:1 Mem:13.05M (0.00M, Peak 13.11M) | Time:00:00.00 | Creating Environment maps
Fra:1 Mem:13.05M (0.00M, Peak 13.11M) | Time:00:00.00 | Caching Point Densities
Fra:1 Mem:13.05M (0.00M, Peak 13.11M) | Time:00:00.00 | Sce: Scene Ve:112 Fa:220 La:1
Fra:1 Mem:13.05M (0.00M, Peak 13.11M) | Time:00:00.00 | Loading voxel datasets
Fra:1 Mem:13.05M (0.00M, Peak 13.11M) | Time:00:00.00 | Sce: Scene Ve:112 Fa:220 La:1
Fra:1 Mem:13.05M (0.00M, Peak 13.11M) | Time:00:00.00 | Sce: Scene Ve:112 Fa:220 La:1
Fra:1 Mem:13.05M (0.00M, Peak 13.11M) | Time:00:00.00 | Volume preprocessing
Fra:1 Mem:13.05M (0.00M, Peak 13.11M) | Time:00:00.00 | Sce: Scene Ve:112 Fa:220 La:1
Fra:1 Mem:13.05M (0.00M, Peak 13.11M) | Time:00:00.00 | Sce: Scene Ve:112 Fa:220 La:1
Fra:1 Mem:27.33M (0.00M, Peak 27.33M) | Time:00:00.00 | Scene, Part 3-100
Fra:1 Mem:34.03M (0.00M, Peak 34.03M) | Time:00:00.00 | Scene, Part 11-100
Fra:1 Mem:38.91M (0.00M, Peak 40.43M) | Time:00:00.00 | Scene, Part 17-100
Fra:1 Mem:39.62M (0.00M, Peak 40.43M) | Time:00:00.01 | Scene, Part 19-100
Fra:1 Mem:40.12M (0.00M, Peak 40.43M) | Time:00:00.01 | Scene, Part 16-100
Fra:1 Mem:37.20M (0.00M, Peak 40.44M) | Time:00:00.01 | Scene, Part 8-100
Fra:1 Mem:37.01M (0.00M, Peak 40.44M) | Time:00:00.01 | Scene, Part 18-100
Fra:1 Mem:37.13M (0.00M, Peak 40.44M) | Time:00:00.01 | Scene, Part 1-100
Fra:1 Mem:40.11M (0.00M, Peak 41.03M) | Time:00:00.01 | Scene, Part 24-100
Fra:1 Mem:38.76M (0.00M, Peak 41.03M) | Time:00:00.01 | Scene, Part 21-100
Fra:1 Mem:37.59M (0.00M, Peak 41.03M) | Time:00:00.01 | Scene, Part 4-100
Fra:1 Mem:38.62M (0.00M, Peak 41.03M) | Time:00:00.01 | Scene, Part 26-100
Fra:1 Mem:36.70M (0.00M, Peak 41.03M) | Time:00:00.01 | Scene, Part 5-100
Fra:1 Mem:35.06M (0.00M, Peak 41.03M) | Time:00:00.01 | Scene, Part 23-100
Fra:1 Mem:35.52M (0.00M, Peak 41.03M) | Time:00:00.01 | Scene, Part 6-100
Fra:1 Mem:35.56M (0.00M, Peak 41.03M) | Time:00:00.01 | Scene, Part 2-100
Fra:1 Mem:33.42M (0.00M, Peak 41.03M) | Time:00:00.01 | Scene, Part 30-100
Fra:1 Mem:32.94M (0.00M, Peak 41.03M) | Time:00:00.01 | Scene, Part 10-100
Fra:1 Mem:33.87M (0.00M, Peak 41.03M) | Time:00:00.01 | Scene, Part 13-100
Fra:1 Mem:34.24M (0.00M, Peak 41.03M) | Time:00:00.01 | Scene, Part 32-100
```

Is there any way to suppress this output?

Comment: By python console do you mean you are using `subprocess.call` to render from a python script?

Comment: I edited my question to clarify how I call render.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is normal output for rendering from the cli and blender doesn't offer an option to reduce it. The way to mute it is to [redirect the output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29#Redirecting_to_and_from_the_standard_file_handles) for the shell, the method varies depending on the shell used. While redirection is normally used to save output to a file you can use `/dev/null` as a file to effectively scrap it as it is output.

For sh or bash (I believe also works in windows terminal) -

```
blender --background --python myscript.py > /dev/null 2>&1
```

for csh

```
blender --background --python myscript.py >& /dev/null
```

The above examples redirect both STDOUT and STDERR to `/dev/null`, to get more control you can direct only STDOUT to `/dev/null` (by only adding `> /dev/null`) which will consume blenders render progress and then print your output to STDERR, which your script can do with `print(myoutput, file=sys.stderr)`

Another approach is to use a script instead of calling blender directly, this will allow you to catch all of blenders output and only send your info to the terminal. By adding a unique tag you can separate your output from blenders progress report.

```
from subprocess import check_output

render_progress = check_output(['blender','--background','--python','myscript.py'])

msg = render_progress.split('*#*#*#')[1]

print(msg)
```

A similar result could also be achieved with a shell script.

Comment: But that will mute all output, also the one that I generate in the script myself. Is there no other way that just mutes the blender-own output?

Comment: While you can alter python's output locations blenders render progress doesn't use the python settings, so you will need to use the shell or a script to control the output.

Comment: Too bad blender is not configurable in this case. Thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081657/how-do-i-prevent-a-c-shared-library-to-print-on-stdout-in-python
It makes a context manager you can use to block the output of specific lines.

```
import os
import sys
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def stdout_redirected(to=os.devnull):
    '''
    import os

    with stdout_redirected(to=filename):
        print("from Python")
        os.system("echo non-Python applications are also supported")
    '''
    fd = sys.stdout.fileno()

    ##### assert that Python and C stdio write using the same file descriptor
    ####assert libc.fileno(ctypes.c_void_p.in_dll(libc, "stdout")) == fd == 1

    def _redirect_stdout(to):
        sys.stdout.close() # + implicit flush()
        os.dup2(to.fileno(), fd) # fd writes to 'to' file
        sys.stdout = os.fdopen(fd, 'w') # Python writes to fd

    with os.fdopen(os.dup(fd), 'w') as old_stdout:
        with open(to, 'w') as file:
            _redirect_stdout(to=file)
        try:
            yield # allow code to be run with the redirected stdout
        finally:
            _redirect_stdout(to=old_stdout) # restore stdout.
                                            # buffering and flags such as
                                            # CLOEXEC may be different
```

Then just use as follows:

```
with stdout_redirected():
     bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```