# How to supress bpy render messages in terminal output?

Tags: python, scripting, blender-internal-render-engine

Using the Blender Python Module `bpy` the rendering process `bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)` is quite verbose:

```
Fra:2 Mem:14.35M (0.00M, Peak 14.50M) | Preparing Scene data
Fra:2 Mem:19.00M (0.00M, Peak 19.01M) | Preparing Scene data
...
Fra:2 Mem:15.00M (0.00M, Peak 33.27M) Sce: Scene Ve:21001 Fa:41576 La:1
Saved: /path/to/output.png Time: 00:00.60 (Saving: 00:00.06)
```

I can't make use of the [proposed solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42882/mute-renderer-output-when-calling-through-script) to omit the script output, because the Blender renderings are embedded in a larger python project using `import bpy` API rather than calling a python script file.

I tried to suppress the output using a python standard method presented [here](http://thesmithfam.org/blog/2012/10/25/temporarily-suppress-console-output-in-python/), but no success.

Is there any way to reduce the verbosity of Blender renderings when using bpy module?

Comment: i didn't try blender as a module but see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/11632982/2987234

Comment: Great, it works!

Comment: if you have a working solution please write a reasonable answer, so it is of some use to others.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following output redirection proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python/11632982#11632982) does work:

```
# redirect output to log file
logfile = 'blender_render.log'
open(logfile, 'a').close()
old = os.dup(sys.stdout.fileno())
sys.stdout.flush()
os.close(sys.stdout.fileno())
fd = os.open(logfile, os.O_WRONLY)

# do the rendering
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)

# disable output redirection
os.close(fd)
os.dup(old)
os.close(old)
```

Comment: cool! even if only relatively few people need to know this answer, at least they don't have to visit a different link now.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081657/how-do-i-prevent-a-c-shared-library-to-print-on-stdout-in-python
It makes a context manager you can use to block the output of specific lines. It is similar to above answer but cleaner.

```
import os
import sys
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def stdout_redirected(to=os.devnull):
    '''
    import os

    with stdout_redirected(to=filename):
        print("from Python")
        os.system("echo non-Python applications are also supported")
    '''
    fd = sys.stdout.fileno()

    ##### assert that Python and C stdio write using the same file descriptor
    ####assert libc.fileno(ctypes.c_void_p.in_dll(libc, "stdout")) == fd == 1

    def _redirect_stdout(to):
        sys.stdout.close() # + implicit flush()
        os.dup2(to.fileno(), fd) # fd writes to 'to' file
        sys.stdout = os.fdopen(fd, 'w') # Python writes to fd

    with os.fdopen(os.dup(fd), 'w') as old_stdout:
        with open(to, 'w') as file:
            _redirect_stdout(to=file)
        try:
            yield # allow code to be run with the redirected stdout
        finally:
            _redirect_stdout(to=old_stdout) # restore stdout.
                                            # buffering and flags such as
                                            # CLOEXEC may be different
```

Then just use as follows:

```
with stdout_redirected():
     bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```